# How to fetch perticular text from string

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I tried to fetch the Some text like starts with Statement_of_Account_ and ends with .zip from given string but i am not able to get the output please help me

```py
import re
s="""

    2019-11-12 15:51:41: Reporting Task started! 2019-11-12 15:51:41: Start running ... 2019-11-12 15:51:44: Creating PDF file (Loan Account 131271) 2019-11-12 15:51:44: Zipping all PDF files ... 2019-11-12 15:51:44: Zipping directory: /tmp/export_reports/Statement_of_Account_1793_1573573901 2019-11-12 15:51:44: All PDF files have been compressed in /tmp/export_reports/Statement_of_Account_1793_1573573901.zip. Output: /tmp/export_reports/Statement_of_Account_1793_1573573901.zip 2019-11-12 15:51:44: S3 file location: https://atom-media.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/report_tasks/Statement_of_Account_1793_1573573901.zip 2019-11-12 15:51:44: Zip file is stored in AWS S3 Storage at: report_tasks/Statement_of_Account_1793_1573573901.zip 2019-11-12 15:51:44: Saving ... 2019-11-12 15:51:44: Done 


    """

    res=re.findall(r"[^Statement_of_Account_]+./(.zip)",s)
```

Comment: Add expected output as well.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need.

```
import re

s='''
2019-11-12 15:51:41: Reporting Task started! 2019-11-12 15:51:41: Start running ... 2019-11-12 15:51:44: Creating PDF file (Loan Account 131271) 2019-11-12 15:51:44: Zipping all PDF files ... 2019-11-12 15:51:44: Zipping directory: /tmp/export_reports/Statement_of_Account_1793_1573573901 2019-11-12 15:51:44: All PDF files have been compressed in /tmp/export_reports/Statement_of_Account_1793_1573573901.zip. Output: /tmp/export_reports/Statement_of_Account_1793_1573573901.zip 2019-11-12 15:51:44: S3 file location: https://atom-media.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/report_tasks/Statement_of_Account_1793_1573573901.zip 2019-11-12 15:51:44: Zip file is stored in AWS S3 Storage at: report_tasks/Statement_of_Account_1793_1573573901.zip 2019-11-12 15:51:44: Saving ... 2019-11-12 15:51:44: Done 
'''
print(re.findall(r"Statement_of_Account_[0-9_]+\.zip", s))
```

**Output:**

```
['Statement_of_Account_1793_1573573901.zip',
 'Statement_of_Account_1793_1573573901.zip',
 'Statement_of_Account_1793_1573573901.zip',
 'Statement_of_Account_1793_1573573901.zip']
```

Comment: Please accept ans(tick symbol) if it solved your problem. Thanks